# using $SPUrl when developing visual web part via visual studio 2013 or 2012 and ascx.g.cs file gets empty!

Tags: visual-web-part, visual-studio-2012

Im developing a Visual Web part for SharePoint 2010 via Visual Studio 2013.
And i want to add css link to visual web part in .ascx file like this:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="<% $SPUrl:~site/_layouts/CompanyName/CSS/AddComment.css %>" runat="server" />
```

But when i do that ".ascx.g.cs" file gets empty and ".ascx.cs" code file will not gonna know any controls.
How can i fix it or use any other way to get current web url?

Comment: try adding the ID attribute to the control, eg. ID="Css1"

Comment: @MdMazzotti: I tested it but unfortunately the problem still exists :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on documentation in MSDN it can't be done using the old regular way.

Visual web parts don't directly support SharePoint server tokens such as **$SPUrl**. For more information, see "Token Restrictions in Sandboxed Visual Web Parts".

Visual web parts in sandboxed solutions can't process standard tokens, such as $SPUrl, that the SharePoint runtime supports. As a result, the URL isn't resolved, and you can't preview the content in Design view in the visual web part designer if you refer to it directly in a script element, such as in the following example:

```
<script src=”<% $SPUrl:~site/SiteAssets/ListOperations.js %>"></script>
```

To work around this limitation and resolve the token, refer to it by using literals:

```
<asp:literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="&lt;script src='" />
<asp:literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text="<% $SPUrl:~site/SiteAssets/ListOperations.js %>" />
<asp:literal ID="Literal3" runat="server" Text="' type='text/javascript' &gt;&lt;/script&gt;" />
```

More info on MSDN: [Troubleshooting SharePoint Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231594.aspx)